# How does static variable work in c? I am a java programmer transitioning to c

Tags: c

How is this code different from the second one? What is the difference between initializing it when declaring and initializing it in the next line?

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
    static int i;
    i=1;
    printf("%d\n",i);
    i++;
    if(i==6)
    {
        return 0;
    }
    main(); // recursive call of main()
}
```

////////////second code////////////////

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
    static int i=1;
    printf("%d\n",i);
    i++;

    if(i==6)
    {
        return 0;
    }
    main(); // recursive call of main()
}
```

Comment: "What is the difference between initializing it when declaring and initializing it in the next line?" First one is indeed initializing, second one is assignment. Initialization of static variables occurs **once**, assignment occurs as many times as needed.

Comment: @arc_lupus: I believe *inability to call `main()` from `main()`* is a feature of C++. In C it is perfectly legal.

Comment: 1st out put is multiple times 1 and then segmentation fault code dumped; 2nd output is 1 2 3 4 5

Comment: You probably get stack overflow in the 1st example after a few recursive calls to `main()`.

Comment: or few hundered, yeah.

Comment: @pmg so in the first code i am intializing the value so after function call the value persists but in second code I am assigning the variable on every call so the value will change to the assingned value on every call. Is this right explanation?

Comment: Yes, that's right. The value of static variables persists across function calls (it's as if the variable exists outside the function). `static` variables are created and initialized (to `0` in the absence of a different initializer) once per program run.

Comment: @pmg: That is new to me, but shows that I am not that deep in C. Is that a way to do a recursive call in C using the main loop?  Nvm., just saw a valid example in C++ which uses that example

Comment: @pmg: a perfect opportunity for tail-call optimization (AKA "goto"). :-)

Answer (score 0):

Static variables persist between function calls, upon re-entring the function the variable will have the same value it was last assigned in the function.

If you initialise it in the declaration it will be initialised once to that value

If you set the value in code it will be set every time the code runs.

Normally main() is only executed once.  but other fuctions are often executed multiple times.

Comment: so in the first code i am intializing the value so after function call the value persists but in second code I am assigning the variable on every call so the value will change to the assingned value on every call. Is this right explanation?

Comment: Yes. That's it.